# Create Interface in Typescript without specifying property name

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I remember there is a way to create, inside an interface, a field without specifying its name, something like this:

```
export interface myInterface{
 [propName:string]:string;
}
```

If I remember well, that sinthax means I can create a field with whatever name I want, something like this:

```
ob:myInterface = {customName: "value"}
```

What I'm trying to do now is to add a new field to that interface, with a specific name, something like this:

```
export interface myInterface{
 [propName:string]:string;
 secondProperties: boolean;
}
```

When I try the code above I get this error:

```
Property 'secondProperties' of type 'boolean' is not assignable to string index type 'string'
```

What is my error?

Comment: Could you please share your problem with https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define all possible types for `[propName: string]`
So you need to do it in this way

```ts
export interface myInterface{
  secondProperties: boolean
  [propName:string]: string | boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I never found a good solution but the problem arises from this.

You are trying to force a property to be of type `boolean & string`, which equals to `never`.

```
type myInterface = {
    [propName:string]: string;
} & {
    secondProperties: boolean;
};

const obj: myInterface = {
    secondProperties: true,
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAtiCSA7YEBOAzAhgY2gXigG8AoKAbTFQHswA5TGCALgGdhUBLRAcwF0mobTjwDcxAL5QAZEVIsI2KogAmABWqRUwDhBYCARlSoAbCJkRjxY4osRsoVfQCsBcJCgw58sqL8EKlNQ00bV0BdgBXCAAaUj8JMSA)

---

Thanks to [@LaytonGB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12425097/laytongb) for hinting, that `|` can be used to make *almost* the type we wanted.

```
type myInterface = {
    [propName:string]: string;
} | {
    secondProperties: boolean;
};

const obj: myInterface = {
    secondProperties: 'string' || true,
    otherProps: 'string only', // booleans will result in error.
};
```

Comment: With the example you have used here, changing the `&` to a vertical line `|` seems to work like OP required.

Comment: Solutions provided by LaytonGB e CyberEternal seem to work

Comment: Though the other methods work, they do not perform the same ideal type-checking. If you create an object, `{ propName1: "foo", secondProperties: true, propName3: false }` then this method (when using an | instead of & on line 3) will show `propName3` to be an error. The other methods will not.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have defined **any** string-named-property of your objects to have a value of string, you can only give `secondProperties` a string value, because `secondProperties` itself is a string.

Alternatively consider this:

```ts
interface myInterface {
  [propName: string]: string | boolean;
  ["secondProperties"]: boolean;
}
```

Because `secondProperties` is a string, and its value returns a boolean, it is not throwing errors.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is really clear :)